# Entity Framework update failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, listview

I have classes generated by entity framework as follows

```
public partial class Datagrid
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsChecked { get; set; }
    }



public partial class SampleDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SampleDbContext()
            : base("name=SampleDbContext")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Datagrid> Datagrids { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a Wpf application where I have a listview containing checkbox per row. I have written the code to retrive the value of the checkbox on buttonclick. When I try to update the database with the selected values of the checkbox it does nothing. Please help..Heres the piece of code..Again all the selection in the checkboxes works fine..I only want to update the Ischecked value in the database with the values that user checks in the checkbox in the front end. So I am assinging dg to avoid validation errors..

```
 try
        {
            int i = 0;
            IEnumerable<CheckBox> myBoxes = FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(this);
            foreach (CheckBox cb in myBoxes)
            {
                Datagrid dg = db.Datagrids.ToList()[i];
                dg.Id=dg.Id;
                dg.Name = dg.Name;
                dg.Location = dg.Location;
                dg.IsChecked = cb.IsChecked;
                db.Datagrids.Add(dg);
                db.SaveChanges();

                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: So you don't get any exception? maybe your web.config's connection string points to another database/instance by mistake? it happens to me a lot.

Comment: Your code doesnt really make any sense since you are saying you want to update a value from database but you are fetching the value and than use .Add which marks the entity to be created/inserted instead of updating.

Comment: Another thing your code wont be fast since you are doing uneccesary querys to database with the Line db.Datagrids.ToList()[i] this line first fetches all entries from the datatable Datagrids but you are only interessted in a certain index. I would recommend reading some tutorials about EF how to do it the correct way.

Comment: I agree this is not the efficient way.. I tried going the MVVM way. I have created a new partial class and made customization to the IsChecked property by specifying OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked") in the setter block..At the view level I am saying <CheckBox IsChecked={Binding IsChecked,mode=two way,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}..But if the checkbox checked changes how do I save that state to the database.. Could you please help if you have good hands on MVVM..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this line seems suspicious:

```
dg.Id=dg.Id;
```

I guess it's just a typo. If so, it's better that you put the actual line of code in your question.

If it's not the issue, then try setting a key attribute to the `id` field (even if you need your own id, just try this, so if it works, you'll have a start point to solve the problem):

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

And then, remove the suspicious (typo?) line:

```
dg.Id=dg.Id;
```

---

**Another way**, which doesn't solve your problem, but worth trying. Put this line:

```
db.Entry(dg).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
```

Instead of:

```
db.Datagrids.Add(dg);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Firstly I had a wrong connection string and then I modified my code and just said db.savechanges() instead of everything..Its working..